# Html paste email is showing hyperlinks disabled

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have an html paste template that is showing the subscription center link as not clickable.
The code is as under:

```
<html>
<body>

<a href="%%subscription_center_url%%" alias="Subscriptions">Subscriptions</a>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please share code and what you have already tried.

Comment: Is this a live email or in the preview?  This link is filled server-side at send, so prior to that it will not be a valid link. (like Adam said below...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't be an actual link until you do a send (not a send preview).  The link will be "wrapped" at send time with the subscriber's attributes, etc.